# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') in react

Tags: reactjs

I hit err TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') suddenly. initially there are no error occurred .

```
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState("1");


const handleStepForward = () => {
    if(parseInt(activeStep) <= 4){
      setActiveStep((parseInt(activeStep) + 1).toString());
    setCompleted((prevCompleted) => [...prevCompleted, activeStep]);
  }
```

How to solve the error? anyone can help ? thanks in advance

Comment: This is not enough code to solve the error, as there is no call to `.indexOf()` in the code you have shown.

Comment: Please share the full stack trace, not just he error message.  It is quite possible that `.indexOf()` is coming from somewhere deep in some component you are using.  The stack trace should show us from where in your code the error is being triggered.

Comment: @GregL I have searched in the project, but I didn't use any .indexof(), is there any possible scenario of the error occurred ?

Comment: Check the full error stack